# Java search functionality

Tags: java

There is a requirement in my Java project where the user will enter the customer name/ number in the front-end 
screen and hit search button, the system should display all the matching customer names with links to the customer details. I have been asked to write

a web service to implement this functionality which will fetch the customer records from the database and display it in the front-end.

Please help me how to do this. thanks in advance!!

Comment: We won't write it for you. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: You could provide a bit more data. For instance the persistance framework you use (JPA, Hibernate, jdbcTemplate) and where your troubles are. If its formulating the SQL then the table schema would be welcome, and if it's Hibernate/JPA the Entity class would be great.

Answer (score 2):

what is the exact problem?

search functionality is easily done through sql:

```
select * from customer where name like '%searchterm%'
```

here is an example from the example depot: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/SelectLike.html

and a webservice can be built through apache axis. This will yield a "full blown" SOAP webservice.

If you want to go for the easy way, just create a jsp or servlet which returns the data as XML. Call this you "REST" webservice.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! What I am looking for is, the user will enter the cusotmer name/ number and hit search button. This parameter should be sent to web service and the service will then search the database for the matching customer names and then return the result in the froent-end in tabular format. In one column, it will have customer name and in another customer number. Can you pls also tell me how to provide a link i.e. when the user click the customer name it should display the customer details.

Comment: wow. that's a lot. It's easy when you know how, but it seems you are missing some basics. Assuming you want to do web based development, I would recommend you to use Grails as framework. You'll find lots of documentation on how to create tables, link to detail pages and how to use web services. It is really easy to get a start with it. http://grails.org/Documentation